# Why does 'wait() method within synchronized block' have deadlock possibility?

Tags: java, synchronized, klocwork

klocwork JD.LOCK.WAIT issue is reported when an Object.wait() method is called while the method is holding two or more locks.

klocwork says that waiting on a monitor while two locks are held may cause deadlock and the issue should be taken into account.

But I cannot understand why this causes deadlock.

Who can help me understand this issue?

Following code is from klockwork.  The JD.LOCK.WAIT issue occurs on line 14 `lock.wait();`.

```
String name;
synchronized void waitForCondition(Object lock) {
    try {
        synchronized(lock) {
            name = "aa";
            lock.wait();            //line 14
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say *t1* enters the `waitForCondition()` method. So *t1* now has `this` as a lock. Meanwhile, some other thread has just acquired `lock` object and is trying call `waitForContion()`.

- *t2* holds `lock` but is waiting for `this` to enter `waitForContion()`.
- *t1* holds `this` but is waiting for `lock` to exit `waitForContion()`.

That is a *deadlock*. Neither of them can make any progress and are waiting on each other.

To avoid this, one strategy is to make sure any thread has all the resources it needs to complete. Here it means that `lock` and `this` can only be acquired together and not otherwise.

Also, when `lock.wait()` is called, only `lock` is released while `this` is not. So, in such a case no thread can call `waitForContion()` on `that` object.

Comment: If I change the synchronized method's parameter from Object lock to byte[] command (for example), I don't need to be worried about deadlock?

Comment: I don't see how that will help. There are two locks(`this` object and the `lock` object), you want to acquire them together and release them together.